# Convert 2 dimensional array to multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do i convert this 2 dimensional array to tree i.e

**This**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => User
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Product
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Login
            [parent_id] => 1

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [name] => Forgot Password
            [parent_id] => 3

        )
}
```

**To**

```
Array
(

    [1] => User => Array
    (
        [3] => Login => Array
        (
            [4] => Forgot Password
        )
    }
    [2] => Product
}
```

i.e create childs based on parent id's

Comment: I think this answer could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328515/convert-php-array-to-json-tree

Comment: your structure is also a graph from bottom-up. define a dummy root, walk your structure with **Breadth-first search** algorithm and populate the child property for each node while walking.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
/**
 * Convert tree array to custom tree
 * 
 * @param array $array given array
 * @param string $child_key child key name
 * @param type $id_key id key name
 * @param type $value_key value key name
 * @return array converted array
 */        
function toCustomSets(array $array, $child_key = 'items', $id_key = 'id', $value_key = 'name')
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if (count($element[$child_key])) {
            $return[$element[$value_key]] = array();
            $return[$element[$value_key]][$element[$id_key]] = $element[$value_key];
            $return[$element[$value_key]] = ($return[$element[$value_key]] + toCustomSets($element[$child_key]));
        } else {
            $return[$element[$id_key]] = $element[$value_key];
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
/**
 * Convert array to tree
 * 
 * @param array $array given array
 * @param int $parent_id parent id
 * @param string $parent_key parent id key name
 * @param string $id_key id key name
 * @return array converted array 
 */
function toTree(array $array, $parent_id = 0, $parent_key = 'parent_id', $id_key = 'id')
{
    $return = array();

    foreach ($array as $element) {
        if ($element[$parent_key] == $parent_id) {
            $element['items'] = toTree($array, $element[$id_key]);
            $return[] = $element;
        }    
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Usage:

```
$data = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'User', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Login', 'parent_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forgot Password','parent_id' => 3));

$tree = toTree($data);
print_r(toCustomSets($tree));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [1] => User
            [Login] => Array
                (
                    [3] => Login
                    [4] => Forgot Password
                )

        )

    [2] => Product
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/cd89a)**

To convert the given 2-dimensional array to a multidimensional array, you can use a `recursive` function to build the hierarchy

`convert_hierarchy()` function is a recursive function that takes the input array and a parent ID as parameters. function calls itself to find its children and creates a nested array with the child ID as the key and the child name as the value

If there are no children, it simply assigns the child name to the parent ID

`top-level` call to convert_hierarchy is made with a default parent ID of 0 to start the process.

```
$inputArray = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'User', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Product', 'parent_id' => 0),
    array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Login', 'parent_id' => 1),
    array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Forgot Password', 'parent_id' => 3)
);

function convert_hierarchy($array, $parentId = 0)
{
    $result = array();

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = convert_hierarchy($array, $item['id']);
            if (!empty($children)) {
                $result[$item['id']][$item['name']] = $children;
            } else {
                $result[$item['id']] = $item['name'];
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$outputArray = convert_hierarchy($inputArray);
// Print the output array
echo '<pre>'; print_r($outputArray); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?