# Converting complex array structure into json

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'd like to convert a complex array in a simple json object. I know how to convert an array into json (json_encode) but my problem is how I could convert my basic array into the following json structure.

**Array structure :**

[image: Array]

**Json Output :**

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Random Access Memories",
    "tracks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Get Lucky",
            "artists": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Daft Punk"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Pharrell Williams"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Touch",
            "artists": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Daft Punk"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "album_artists": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Daft Punk"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pharrell Williams"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like an array, it looks like an image.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php check this link.. it will help you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328515/convert-php-array-to-json-tree

Comment: It is an illustration of my array. I uploaded it to make it more visual...

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't particularly good practise, but I'd loop through the initial array, or image, as displayed in the OP, to get an array of tracks, and then create a separate array for the json using the album name and album id of the first element in the tracks providing that all albums and album ids are the same.

```
$tracks = array();
$albumArtists = array();
foreach ($yourArrayNotAsAnImage as $track) {
    $tracks[] = $track;
    $albumArtists[] = array("name" => $track['artist_name'], "id" => $track['artist_id']);
}

$daftP = array("name" => $tracks[0]['album'], "id" => $tracks[0]['album_id'], "tracks" => $tracks, "album_artists" => $albumArtists);

echo json_encode($daftP);
```