# Hirearchy tree json using php?

Tags: php, json

I have json like this. i have try this [Convert PHP array to JSON tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328515/convert-php-array-to-json-tree) but always fail when i create.

```
{
  "name": "Level 7",
  "value": "4.5",
  "parents": [
    {
      "name": "Level 5",
      "value": "Gery",
      "parents": [
        {
          "name": "Level 2",
          "value": "Robert"
        },
        {
          "name": "Level 1",
          "value": "Rio"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 6",
      "value": "GEO",
      "parents": [
        {
          "name": "Level 3",
          "value": "Lion"
        },
        {
          "name": "Level 4",
          "value": "Pery"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How to create json hierachy from php?

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'Level 1', 'value' => 'Rio', 'parents' => 'Level 7/Level 5'),
    array('name' => 'Level 2', 'value' => 'Robet', 'parents' => 'Level 7/Level 5'),
    array('name' => 'Level 3', 'value' => 'Lion', 'parents' => 'Level 7/Level 6'),
    array('name' => 'Level 4', 'value' => 'Pery', 'parents' => 'Level 7/Level 6'),
    array('name' => 'Level 5', 'value' => 'Gery', 'parents' => 'Level 7'),
    array('name' => 'Level 6', 'value' => 'GEO', 'parents' => 'Level 7'),
       array('name' => 'Level 7', 'value' => '4.5', 'parents' => 'none'),
);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `json_encode`?

Comment: i confuse how to insert the child value. @Vohuman

Comment: If you can't generate the expected PHP array before JSON encoding then that's a different problem. In that case you should rephrase the question and post the relevant code that reproduces the "problem".

Comment: Please, show your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

If the json is stored as a string, you can convert it to a PHP object with `json_decode`.

```
$object = json_decode($json);
```

If it's a PHP object, you can convert it to a string with `json_encode`.

```
$string = json_decode($object);
```